# Getting error like "The system cannot find the path specified." while exporting the crystal report in the pdf format in the .net console application

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, windows-10, console-application, .net-4.7.2

I have written the simple code for exporting the crystal report .rpt in the pdf format below is the code for the reference.

```cs
// Create a Crystal Report document
ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();

// Load the Crystal Report file
reportDocument.Load("Report.rpt");

// Set the database connection for the report
reportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon(username, password, server, database);

// Set the parameter value
reportDocument.SetParameterValue("cRef", 12);

// Export the report to PDF

string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
string pdfPath = Path.Combine(desktopPath, "Report.pdf");
reportDocument.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, pdfPath);

//MemoryStream pdfStream = (MemoryStream)reportDocument.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);

// Save the memory stream to a PDF file

// File.WriteAllBytes(pdfPath, pdfStream.ToArray());


// Close and dispose of the database connection and report document
reportDocument.Close();
reportDocument.Dispose();
```

The Error as follows

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): The system cannot find the path specified.
> at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ReportSourceClass.Export(ExportOptions pExportOptions, RequestContext pRequestContext)
> at CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
> at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
> at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.Export(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
> at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Export(ExportOptions options)

I have tried this same code on the multiple devices but for the one device I am getting this error.

All device (Windows 10) has the .net framework version 4.7.2 and the SAP Crystal Reports 13.0 runtime (32-bit) version 13.0.12.1494

The machine where I got the error does not has the .net framework version 4.7.2, so I have installed that on the machine.

Comment: You are putting the data into you desktop which only you and an Admin has access.  Better to put file on a shared drive that everybody can access.

Comment: I have also tested that scenario , but the issue is still arriving for the one desktop. Not for  other desktops.

Comment: What is the value of pdfPath?

Comment: pdfPath will be the desktopPath +"Report.pdf". It will be the desktop only in this case. But I have given also the direct path to the D drive.

Comment: Check path with a file explorer and make sure it is accurate.  When accessing a file on a remote machine As Admin you need to replace the colon in the path with a dollar sign.

Answer (score 0):

If the destination path is a mapped drive and the application on that machine is set to Run As Administrator, it wouldn't "see" the mapped drive unless you take an extra step or unless you change the mapped drive path to UNC path.

If that was not the issue, check permissions on the folder.

Comment: If an admin, you need to replace the colon in the path name with a dollar sign.